# Cannot limit post revisions

Tags: revisions

I don't know why but I cannot limit post revisions even though I've added the code

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );
```

Is there anything wrong in adding the code to wp-config file? Here are images of the problem.

[image: Code added to wp-config file]

Post revisions not limiting

[image: Post revisions not limiting]

Comment: There is an issue with this feature if there are already post revisions saved. There is a couple of threads on the net about this. Here is a [quick search](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&redir_esc=&client=tablet-android-samsung&source=android-browser-type&v=141338691&qsubts=1426145975883&action=devloc&q=WP_POST_REVISIONS)

Answer (score 1):

The option works from the moment you add it to your wp-config.php file. You can try to remove the old revisions using something like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/) Just back-up your db first.

Comment: Actually, I added that piece of code when I first installed WordPress. But the post revision limit is clearly not working.